# ; [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, npm

I have cloned a GitHub repository and did `npm` I in the root directory and also in the client then made a file in the config for development. When I run `npm run dev` nodemon crashes always give result as compiled with a warning.

Comment: Hi there! Is it possible that you share this repo so we can try reproducing the error locally?

Comment: yes sure!https://github.com/jaewonhimnae/boilerplate-mern-stack.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue. it was just because the node_module is cached. so I did delete the node mode module and pakckage-lock.json in both client and server-side and then I reinstall the node module so to fix my issues

Comment: You should accept this answer so that it can be obvious to others that the issue is solved.

Comment: Done Thank you for your concern.